# Highcharts data filter Conigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, highcharts

I created a highchart to view issued data in a MySQL table. Then I want to filter those issued data itemwise on the chart. I used the following code to do that:

### Controller (Chart_issue.php)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 
class Chart_issue extends CI_Controller {
 
 public function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->model('data'); 
 }
  
 public function index()
 {
$data['item_list'] = $this->data->fetch_item();
 $this->load->view('charts/chart_issue');
 } 
  
 public function data()


    { 
if ($this->input->post('item_id') )
        {
 $data = $this->data->get_issued_data();  
 $category = array();
 $category['name'] = 'Item';
  
 $series1 = array();
 $series1['name'] = 'Issued Qty'; 

 $series2 = array();
 $series2['name'] = 'Date'; 
  
 foreach ($data as $row)
 {
 $category['data'][] = $row->item; 
 $series1['data'][] = $row->issued_qty;
 $series2['data'][] = $row->billed_date;  
 }
  
 $result = array();
 array_push($result,$category);
 array_push($result,$series1, $series2); 
   
 print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
 }
```

}
}

### Model (Data.php)

```
function get_issued_data($id)
{      
    $this->db->select('sur.update_stock_id, sus.branch_id, sus.request_no, sus.billed_date, store_branch.branch_name AS branch,
    si.item_id, si.item_name AS item,   tf.avqty,   sur.r_qty as r_qty, sur.ap_qty as ap_qty, 
    tf1.issued_qty');
    $this->db->from('store_update_request sur');
    $this->db->join('store_update_stock sus', 'sus.update_stock_id=sur.update_stock_id', 'left');       
    $this->db->join('store_branch', 'sus.branch_id=store_branch.branch_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('store_item si', 'sur.item=si.item_id', 'left');        
    
    $this->db->join('(select update_stock_id, item, is_qty AS issued_qty 
        from store_update_issue         
        where store_update_issue.status=1 
        ) AS tf1', 
        'si.item_id=tf1.item AND sur.update_stock_id = tf1.update_stock_id','left' );
                
    $this->db->join('(select item, sum(qty)  AS avqty 
        from store_update_stock_details             
        where store_update_stock_details.status=1 
        group by item) AS tf', 'si.item_id=tf.item', 'left');
    $this->db->where(array('sus.status' => 1 , 'store_item.item_id' => $id));
$query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return false;
}
```

View (chart_issue.php)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                
                
                title: {
                    text: 'Item Issued Summary',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['']
                },
                yAxis: [{
                    title: {
                        text: 'Issues'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                
            ],           
            
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                }, 
                
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                plotOptions: {
                 column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

                series: []
            }

            $.getJSON("data", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];                
                
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });

// ]]></script>

<a href="<?= site_url('welcome') ?>"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Back to Home"></a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Item Issued Data</h3>
                        
                    </div>
                    <body>   

                    
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select name="item" id="item" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Item</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($item_list->result_array() as $row)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row["item_id"].'">'.$row["item_name"].'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>                       
                </div>                   
                
            </div>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</body>                  
                    
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/highcharts.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/exporting.js'></script>
```

### Error

Can't populate item list in the dropdown and filtering not work.

### Desired Output

Filter a chart data as per selected item through the dropdown.

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Can you pinpoint where the problem is exactly? On the side of PHP, mySQL, JavaScript or specifically the Highcharts library? If the problem is in the JS configuration, are you able to simplify the code by replacing the PHP code with sample data and reproducing the error in an online editor like JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sun57geh/?

Comment: @ 
Michał
 . Highcharts library is working properly. Generated chart can't be filtering as per item names. JavaScript error is occurig.

Comment: Since you have a problem strictly related to JavaScript, and more specifically with JQuery, it would be best for you to close this topic and ask a question focusing on these issues without the PHP code or the library with which the problem is not related and reproducing it in an online editor, in you'll get an answer faster that way